# The sum of $(1+i)^x + (1-i)^x$ in a proof

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

My friend sent me an interesting question:
For all non-negative integers $x$, show that:

$$(1+i)^x + (1-i)^x = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor x/2\rfloor}\binom{x}{2j}(-1)^j$$

I've tried induction on $x$, but that didn't seem to do the trick. Some hints as to how to approach this proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @xpaul You forgot to change the $x$ in the top bound of the summation into an $n$. I can't change it because I submitted an edit right when you did.

Comment: I don't know why I can't change it.

Comment: I forgot to add a term (2) at the start. My bad!

Comment: why have you asked this question twice?

Comment: @Ysera Two things I would like to convey to you: 1) I added some details to my original answer below, so do take a look if you are still interested in the subject; 2) there is a certain natural tradition of syntax in the context of algebraic expressions involving complex numbers, tradition which recommends using $x$ for generic *real* numbers and $m, n, p$ etc for generic *natural* numbers, such as exponents in particular; having $x$ denote a natural exponent is very awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use
$$ (1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j. $$
Using
$$ i^{2j}+(-i)^{2j}=2(-1)^j, i^{2j+1}+(-i)^{2j+1}=0 $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&(1+i)^x + (1-i)^x \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^x\binom{x}{j}\bigg(i^j+(-i)^j\bigg)\\
&=&2\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor x/2\rfloor}\binom{x}{2j}(-1)^j
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I've also tried this, but still can't seem to get anywhere. If I add them together, I can't find a way to transform the bounds of summation into what we have on the RS.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: sorry, but I just don't see how you went from the previous line to the last line. That's just where I'm confused.

Comment: For $j$ being odd, terms are cancelled.

Comment: Yes, but how does that change the bounds of summation?

Comment: Let $j=2k\le x$ and then $k\le \lfloor x/2\rfloor$ and change $k$ into $j$.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit steps in processing the above relation -- which @xpaul has left out, as they are quite simple -- are as follows:

$$\begin{align}
&(1+\mathrm{i})^n+(1-\mathrm{i})^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\mathrm{i}^k+(-\mathrm{i})^k\right)\\
&=\sum_{\substack{0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\\k \in 2\mathbb{N}}}\binom{n}{k}\left(\mathrm{i}^k+(-\mathrm{i})^k\right)+\sum_{\substack{0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\\k \in 2\mathbb{N}+1}}\binom{n}{k}\left(\mathrm{i}^k+(-\mathrm{i})^k\right)\\
&=\sum_{h=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}\binom{n}{2h}\left(\mathrm{i}^{2h}+(-\mathrm{i})^{2h}\right)\\
&=\sum_{h=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}\binom{n}{2h}\left((-1)^h+(-1)^h\right)\\
&=2\sum_{h=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}(-1)^h\binom{n}{2h},
\end{align}$$
where we need to bear in mind two important justifications for the above:

- for *odd* $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we obviously have $\mathrm{i}^k+(-\mathrm{i})^k=\mathrm{i}^k-\mathrm{i}^k=0$
- the map:
  $$\begin{align}
  \left\{h \in \mathbb{N} \mid h \leqslant \left[\frac{n}{2}\right]\right\} &\to \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid 2 \mid k \wedge k \leqslant n \}\\
  h&\mapsto 2h
  \end{align}$$
  is a bijection on the grounds of which we can perform a *bijective change of summation index*.

---

**P.S.** The relation that you seek to prove is valid in a more general setting, as it relies on the polynomial identity:
$$(X+\mathrm{i}Y)^n+(X-\mathrm{i}Y)^n=2\sum_{k=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}X^{n-2k}Y^{2k},$$
considered in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[X, Y]$.

However, given your particular choice of complex numbers $1\pm \mathrm{i}$ it would be a pity to pass the occasion of noticing a remarkable property they exhibit and which enables us to give yet another description of the general sum you are studying. For simplicity let us write $\varepsilon=\frac{1+\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and notice that:
$$\varepsilon^2=\frac{1+\mathrm{i}^2+2\mathrm{i}}{2}=\mathrm{i},$$
which furthermore entails the relations $\varepsilon^4=-1$ respectively $\varepsilon^8=1$. In other words, $\varepsilon$ is a so-called *primitive* $8$-th root of unity.

With this in mind we infer that:
$$\begin{align*}
(1+\mathrm{i})^n+(1-\mathrm{i})^n &=\left(\sqrt{2}\varepsilon\right)^n+\left(\sqrt{2}\overline{\varepsilon}\right)^n\\
&=\sqrt{2}^n\left(\varepsilon^n+\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{2}^n\frac{\varepsilon^{2n}+1}{\varepsilon^n}\\
&=\sqrt{2}^n\frac{\mathrm{i}^n+1}{\varepsilon^n}\\
&=\sqrt{2}^n\begin{cases}
2, &n \equiv 0 \pmod{8}\\
\sqrt{2}, &n \equiv 1, 7  \pmod{8}\\
0, &n \equiv 2, 6 \pmod{8}\\
-\sqrt{2}, &n \equiv 3, 5 \pmod{8}\\
-2, &n \equiv 4 \pmod{8}
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
2^{\frac{n}{2}+1}, &n \equiv 0 \pmod{8}\\
2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}, &n \equiv 1, 7 \pmod{8}\\
0, &n \equiv 2, 6 \pmod{8}\\
-2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}, & n \equiv 3, 5 \pmod{8}\\
-2^{\frac{n}{2}+1}, & n \equiv 4 \pmod{8},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

relations from which you can in particular obtain an answer to the related question you posted separately on this forum.